# UMVU Estimator of Bernoulli Distribution

Tags: statistics

I am working on this question, and I got stuck.
Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli variables with success probability p.

$\hat{p}_n= \frac{(X_1 + ... +X_n)}{n} $

I was able to show that $\sqrt{n} (\hat{p}^2_n - p^2) \rightarrow N(0, 4p^3(1-p))$ by using the delta method; $\sqrt{n} (\hat{p}_n - p) \rightarrow N(0, p(1-p))$.

Now I am trying to find the UMVU estimator $\delta_n$ of $\sigma^2 = 4p^3(1-p))$. From what I understand the UMVU is going to be the bias corrected version of the MLE. However, I am not sure how to proceed. I would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Rao - Blackwell & Lehmann - Scheffé together,  the UMVUE is

$$\mathbb{E}[T|S]$$

Where $T$ is an unbiased estimator for $p$ and $S$ is a Complete and Sufficient Statistic.

Let's set $ T=X_1$ and $S=\Sigma_i X_i$

$$\mathbb{E}[T|S]=\mathbb{P}[X_1=1|\Sigma_i X_i=s]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[X_1]\mathbb{P}[\Sigma_i X_i=s|X_1=1]}{\mathbb{P}[\Sigma_i X_i=s]}  = $$

$$=\frac{\mathbb{P}[X_1]\mathbb{P}\Big[\Sigma_{i=2}^n X_i=s-1]}{\mathbb{P}[\Sigma_i X_i=s]}=\frac{p\binom{n-1}{s-1}p^{s-1}(1-p)^{n-s}   }{\binom{n}{s}p^s(1-p)^{n-s}}=\frac{s}{n}=\overline {X}_n$$